# What does this mean in my website console: "JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1 jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1:2 "

Tags: wordpress, web, console, jqmigrate

My website gets "No Secure" and "no https".  After I tried to fix this problem, and I change all the http: domain name to https:domain name, and I update the WordPress, my website console shows this: "JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1 jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1:2 "

What does this mean?

Comment: Can confirm this is a message is from a plugin "jquery-migrate" which provides access to missing APIs that are removed when upgrading to a newer version of jquery. https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate#readme

Comment: [`jquery-migrate`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate#readme) is not intended to be used in production. It should be used to see what is deprecated in newer versions in order to resolve them with recommended alternatives. After everything is resolved this package should be removed before pushing it to production (or you can use it as a devDependency if you're using Node.js).

Answer (score 8):

This is a console.log message coming from one of your plugins or browser extensions. Apparently it is not bad (otherwise it would be red colored error or yellow warning) but annoying.

Sometimes those can pop up as part of google chrome extensions (since some of them use jquery as dependency).

This message basically indicates that a version of jquery that helps to migrate old versions is used.